# Compile fail on 32bit linux for attribute TI

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, x86, x86-64

I have a project built in C++, which compiles great on CentOS 6, 64 bit (VM).  However, when I compile it under CentOS 6, 32-bit (VM), I get the error below.

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -Dsecast=1 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../../project -I../../src -I../../../geoip/libmaxminddb-0.5.3/include -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtXml -I/usr/include/qt5/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I../../build/moc -I. -o ../../build/obj/controller.o ../../src/controller.cpp
In file included from ../../src/geoip/geoipdb.h:14,
                 from ../../src/controller.cpp:34:
../../../geoip/libmaxminddb-0.5.3/include/maxminddb.h:55: error: unable to emulate ‘TI’
```

What is this TI attribute error and how do I get rid of it?

When I look at the maxminddb.h file the first typedef (below) is where the error is caused.

```
#if !(MMDB_UINT128_IS_BYTE_ARRAY)
#if MMDB_UINT128_USING_MODE
typedef unsigned int mmdb_uint128_t __attribute__ ((__mode__(TI)));
#else
typedef unsigned __int128 mmdb_uint128_t;
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: I think the underlying issue is that `MMDB_UINT128_IS_BYTE_ARRAY` should be 1 on a 32 bit CentOS 6 system as defined in the `maxminddb_config.h` header. I would suggest [filing a bug upstream](https://github.com/maxmind/libmaxminddb/issues?state=open), including both your `config.log` for the libmaxminddb build and your `maxminddb_config.h` header file.